# How to cut a desired shape out with desired depth of a mesh on VR?

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes, mesh, virtual-reality, oculus

I am creating my first Unity project which is a  , and I am struggling with a particular issue.

I need to create      that includes:

- A curved incision only applied on human flesh surface(mesh surface)
- Variable depth based on user interaction
- The ability to insert objects into the incision

I found a video demonstrating exactly what I am trying to achieve, but unfortunately, the source code is not available and the owner has not responded to my requests for assistance.

Any advice, suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zhOj0iSXVE&t=1s

Comment: Just to be clear, you never actually want to split the mesh into multiple parts, only to cut specific grooves/tranches out of it? Is the mesh in question fixed in place? Or is it subject to physics itself? I ask as Unity has an issue with concave colliders (which your edited mesh would be) when neither are static.